# tableau dashboard filter like this

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to create a tableau dashboard filter like following image? any sample or example please.
When user clicks on the left the data is displayed right on the map.

https://www.humanitarianresponse.info/en/operations/afghanistan/3w

Thank you

Comment: That is an Action Filter. Here's how they work. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

we can create this with the action filter and should have related data in both the sheets.